# iText bytearray not giving a workable output

Tags: android, arrays, itext

I'm pretty new here so do ask if you need any more information.

As it stands i've a section of code which writes to the SD card. It writes .jpegs, and it is giving them all variable kb sizes like you'd expect from a pdf full of images. However, when I select them on the tablet it's 'Unable to open photo', and when I open them on my computer it doesn't allow it either so there's obviously some level of corruption that i'm missing.

I've also tested the image.length and that seems to be working too in terms of outputting many different byte sizes.

```
    try {
    InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("iText-40.pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
        PdfObject pdfobj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if (pdfobj != null && pdfobj.isStream()) {
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) pdfobj;
            PdfObject pdfsubtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
            if (pdfsubtype != null
                    && pdfsubtype.toString().equals(
                            PdfName.IMAGE.toString())) {
                byte[] image = PdfReader
                        .getStreamBytesRaw((PRStream) stream);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getParentFile(), i + ".jpeg"));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                System.out.println(image.length);

                out.write(image);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            }
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e2) {
    System.out.println(e2);
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction atleast as to what i'm doing wrong i'd be greatful. By the way, i've tried a few things with bitmap factory to try and make it work such as re-opening the file with bitmap factory hoping that for some reason it might fix it. It didn't. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: There are different types of bitmap images in PDF and you treat them all as if they were jpegs. So no wonder you get broken jpegs. Why don't you use image extraction capabilities in iText's parser package?

Comment: as far as i'm aware they all use swing which isn't an android ported library, if you could tell me otherwise i'd appreciate it

Comment: Concerning *Swing uise*: iText is available in a special version built for Android and Google App Engine, [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg). I'd try that version.

Comment: I had a go on it, but once I found the image object I wasn't able to do anything with it in terms of extracting. Could you tell me which function works to do this as I spent ages looking for a potential way of outputting it?

Comment: Have you tried whether the iText sample [ExtractImages.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=284) using [MyImageRenderListener.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=283) works on Android? This sample after all represents the way one generally should try image extraction with iText.

Comment: Yeah, if you cast your eyes half way down one of its dependencies: ImageType. "/ Adding a java.awt.Image
        java.awt.Image awtImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(RESOURCE); ". The awt/swing stuff isn't in android. I did actually get pretty clsoe too with an android port of pdfbox but the guy left out write2outputstream or write2file on the objects that i needed them on. I've contacted him, he said he might be able to do it so i'll let you know if it's of any interest to you.

Comment: hey mkl, I ended up finding how to do it without swing but with itextG. thanks, you put me on the right path :)

Comment: Unfortunate, this use of awt. But as I see in your editing your answer, iTextG seems to have been the answer anyway... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding out how to do what I needed to do with iText with a different method:

You need iTextG library (itextg-5.5.3.jar), scpkix-jdk15on.1.47.0.1.jar & scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar

inside where want to call it from:

```
public static final String RESULT = "/storage/sdcard0/dirAtExtStorage/Img%s.%s";

public void extractImages(String filename)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener(RESULT);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        parser.processContent(i, listener);
    }
}
```

inside MyImageRendererListener.java:

```
public class MyImageRenderListener implements RenderListener{

private String path;

public MyImageRenderListener(String path) {
    this.path = path;

  }



@Override
public void beginTextBlock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void endTextBlock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    try {
        System.out.print("renderImage");
        String filename;
        FileOutputStream os;
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
        if (image == null) return;
        filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), image.getFileType());
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void renderText(TextRenderInfo arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  }
```

enjoy guys